# how to disabled imported module in angular+2 based on environment variable?

Tags: angular, openid-connect

I'm using two behavior of authentication (JWT API & SSO) so I'd like to un import the OIDC module when using the regular authentication and so on.

Comment: Dont import it in the first place.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.